# Trigger a function in PHPFox

Tags: phpfox

In PHPFox site i want to trigger a function each time when activity point increases. Is it possible from one file updation ?  Otherwise i will have to change in each module(e.g. photo,blog,poll,comment etc), whichever increases activity point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook "user.service_activity_update" to write a plug-in for this. Here is a tutorial on how to write [plug-ins](http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/264/primer-on-hooks-plugins/)